# Javascript function to validate time 00:00 with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, function, time

I am trying to create a javascript function with regular expression to validate and format the time 24 hours, accepting times without semicolon and removing spaces.
Examples:
If the user types `"0100"`, `" 100"` or `"100 "` it would be accepted but formatted to `"01:00"`
If the user types `"01:00"` it would be accepted, with no need to format.

Thanks.

Comment: what if user types 25:78 - an invalid time?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```js
function formatTime(time) {
    var result = false, m;
    var re = /^\s*([01]?\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)\s*$/;
    if ((m = time.match(re))) {
        result = (m[1].length === 2 ? "" : "0") + m[1] + ":" + m[2];
    }
    return result;
}
alert(formatTime(" 1:00"));
alert(formatTime("1:00 "));
alert(formatTime("1:00"));
alert(formatTime("2100"));
alert(formatTime("90:00")); // false
```

Any call with invalid input format will return false.

Comment: I fixed it for "27:00" to be invalid.

Comment: Thanks Ocus, this function does the job.

Comment: Thanks Ocus, this function does the prefect job for what I need.

Comment: How should this regex be extended if "11" should be evaluated to "11:00"?

Comment: @acme: While I don't think it is relevant, this is how the function should look: `function formatTime(time) {
    var result = false, m;
    var re = /^\s*([01]?\d|2[0-3])(:?([0-5]\d))?\s*$/;
    if ((m = time.match(re))) {
        result = (m[1].length == 2 ? "" : "0") + m[1] + ":" + (m[2] || "00");
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(formatTime("11"));`

BUT `console.log(formatTime("110"));` while give you "01:10" and not "11:00".
You have been warned ;)