# how to solve time regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

After reviewing [Time validation question by Amra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048460/javascript-function-to-validate-time-0000-with-regular-expression)

I have created a regexp for my needs

> var re = /^\s*([01]?\d|1[0-2]):?([00,30]\d)\s*$/;

my intention is to allow only the hour and half an hour interval times

ie: "12:00","01:00","12:30","01:30", etc

This regexp almost works, it returns false when "01:10" but it returns the value when i enter "01:01"...."01.09", it has to be false.

Please help me

And please describe this regexp in detail..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[00,30]` does not do what you think it does. `[]` groups in a regexp are *character classes* - sets of characters that can be matched, for instance `[a-z]` matches a single lowercase letter, not the string "a-z".

Try this instead:

```
var re = /^\s*(0?\d|1[0-2]):?(00|30)\s*$/;
```

`(00|30)` matches either `00` or `30` and nothing else - `|` is the regex "or" operator.

Comment: Please describe me var re = /^\s*(0?\d|1[0-2]):?(00|30)\s*$/;

Comment: `^\s*` = not a whitespace 0-n times; 
`(0?\d|1[0-2])` = either `0?\d` or `1[0-2]`; 
`0?\d` = a `0` 0 or 1 time, followed by a digit; 
`1[0-2]` = a `1` followed by a `0`, a `1` or a `2`; 
`:?` = a `:` 0 or 1 time; 
`(00|30)` = either `00` or `30`;
`^...$` = kind of *should match the all string, not any substring*

Comment: Thank you Amber for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow for 24 hour time, you can change Amber's answer slightly to:

```
/^\s*([0-1]?\d|2[0-3]):?(00|30)\s*$/
```